# What can happen if I catch an error?

Tags: java, error-handling

Surprisingly [google didn't describe any catastrophic scenarios](https://www.google.cz/search?q=what%20happens%20if%20you%20catch%20error%20java) my twisted mind craved for.

Anywhere I read, catching errors is discouraged. Basic rule seems to be that if your application produced error, it's already dead, beyond saving. So if you catch errors in your `main` function, does your program turn into zombie?

How can even error be caught if the program is already collapsing? Can catching errors do something real bad? Which errors are worst and which are sometimes caught? Could you describe a little test case that can produce the errors (like really produce them, not just throw them) so that I can see that they do if I catch them and ignore them?

Comment: @FUVM I'm not asking when, I ask **what happens**. If you are so convinced this as likely to be duplicate, link to an exact answer that answers my questions because I've already read post you link to.

Comment: See when you catch error... you are making jvm run even on the abnormal conditions... nothing else is gonna happen... Like if a library is not found... and you catch that error...

Comment: Well something must happen. Something is happening all the time and it will not stop as long as universe exists. So whatever it is, it's answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much happens except that the thrown object is caught. Your process can be in a bad place, though, depending on what caused the error.

A [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) is pretty undramatic to catch - it's thrown when the maximum stack depth is exceeded, and since it then starts popping the call stack, it's no longer a problem (unless you try calling the offending method again).

```
class SO {
    static int stackOverflow(){ return stackOverflow(); }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            stackOverflow();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println("Oh well, life goes on.");
        }
    }
}
```

Other errors, like [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), are somewhat more problematic - there will still be too much memory used after it's been thrown. Some are directly fatal, like [`ClassFormatError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassFormatError.html), which means that you're trying to load a broken class file (and it's usually thrown in places where you can't catch it).

Other `Error`s are somewhere inbetween. [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html), for example, is thrown when a programmer-defined condition (like `assert answer == 42;`) isn't met, but only if you've enabled assertions.

Long story short, though: If you're catching specific errors, you're probably doing the wrong thing (unless you *really* know what you're doing!). If you're running a server app and want it to keep running, you're probably better of letting the current thread or process die and have it restarted by some kind of monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Catching an Exception or Error is not a good idea, unless;

- you can do something useful with it.
- as a last resort to ensure it is logged correctly or in a submitted `Runnable` to an ExecutorService. In this case catching `Throwable` may be desirable.

Nothing terrible will happen if you catch an Error, however you can't pretend it didn't happen either (i.e. you can't just continue as if it didn't matter)

Note: not catching an error can be a bad thing for multi-threaded applications.  This is because an uncaught error only closes the current thread.  If there are multiple threads, they will keep running if at least one is not a *daemon*  This can leave a program running but in a bad state.

> I ask what happens.

Nothing special, you catch it and you can deal with it or log it.

Comment: If I get the `OutOfMemoryError`, how can I log it? Memory is full, so I suppose no more objects can be created. Not even a String to be sent to log.

Comment: @TomášZato correct, unless you free some memory first. e.g. say you are trying to create a large object structure, which fails part way.  When you catch the error, this object might be discarded and you have plenty of memory to log this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about catching Exceptions?  There are two types of Exceptions checked and unchecked.  The reason to catch an Exception as simple as catching a programmer defined Exception which enables the user to reenter the data.  This normally applies to checked Exceptions.

Unchecked Exceptions cannot be recovered from and you might ask why catch them at all?  Perhaps the developer wants to catch it to log the conditions which caused the Exception and to better troubleshoot the issue.

Here is an article discussing them both.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html

Comment: No, I am not talking about exceptions, I'm talking about errors.